# Can't compile matrix multiplication

Tags: c

Hey I got this error and I tried like 10 solutions and neither works. I want to load 2 matrix, each one from its own txt file then to multiply them. I can't compile cause of LNK1120 and LNK2019 errors.

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


FILE *macierz1, *macierz2, *fw;
char *line = malloc(1000);
int count = 0;
macierz1 = fopen("macierz1.txt", "r");
    if (macierz1 == NULL) {``
    printf("nie można otworzyć", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
}


macierz2 = fopen("macierz2.txt", "r");
if (macierz2 == NULL) {
    printf("nie można otworzyć", argv[2]);
    exit(1);
}

double *data = (double*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(double));
if (data == NULL)
{
    printf("błąd lokowania pamięci");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
getline(&line, &count, macierz1);
int read = -1, cur = 0, columCount1 = 0;
while (sscanf(line + cur, "%lf%n", &data[columCount1], &read) == 1)
{
    cur += read; columCount1++;
}

int rowCount1 = 1;
while (getline(&line, &count, macierz1) != -1) { rowCount1++; }
printf("%d\n", columCount1);
printf("%d\n", rowCount1);

getline(&line, &count, macierz2);
read = -1, cur = 0;
int columCount2 = 0;
while (sscanf(line + cur, "%lf%n", &data[columCount2], &read) == 1)
{
    cur += read; columCount2++;
}

int rowCount2 = 1;
while (getline(&line, &count, macierz2) != -1) { rowCount2++; }
printf("%d\n", columCount2);
printf("%d\n", rowCount2);
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

int **mat1 = (int **)malloc(rowCount1 * sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < rowCount1; i++)
    mat1[i] = (int *)malloc(columCount1 * sizeof(int));

fseek(macierz1, 0, SEEK_SET);

for (i = 0; i < rowCount1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < columCount1; j++)
        fscanf(macierz1, "%d", &mat1[i][j]);
}

i = 0;
j = 0;

printf("\n\n");
//print matrix 1
for (i = 0; i < rowCount1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < columCount1; j++)
        printf("%d", mat1[i][j]);

    printf("\n");
}

i = 0;
j = 0;
int **mat2 = (int **)malloc(rowCount2 * sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < rowCount2; i++)
    mat2[i] = (int *)malloc(columCount2 * sizeof(int));

fseek(macierz2, 0, SEEK_SET);

for (i = 0; i < rowCount2; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < columCount2; j++)
        fscanf(macierz2, "%d", &mat2[i][j]);
}

i = 0;
j = 0;

printf("\n\n");
//print matrix 2
for (i = 0; i < rowCount2; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < columCount2; j++)
        printf("%d", mat2[i][j]);

    printf("\n");
}

i = 0;

int **mat3 = (int **)malloc(rowCount1 * sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < rowCount1; i++)
    mat3[i] = (int *)malloc(columCount2 * sizeof(int));
i = 0;
j = 0;
int k = 0;
int sum = 0;

if (columCount1 != rowCount2)
{
    puts("The number of columns in Matrix 1 is not same as the number of rows in Matrix 2");
    exit(1);
}

//multiplication of two matrices
for (i = 0; i<rowCount1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j<columCount2; j++)
    {
        mat3[i][j] = 0;
        for (k = 0; k<columCount1; k++)
        {
            mat3[i][j] = mat3[i][j] + mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
        }
    }
}


//print multiplication result
printf("\n\nResult = \n\n");

for (i = 0; i < rowCount1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < columCount2; j++)
        printf("%d", mat3[i][j]);

    printf("\n");
}
for (i = 0; i< rowCount1; i++)
    free(mat1[i]);
free(mat1);

for (i = 0; i< rowCount2; i++)
    free(mat2[i]);
free(mat2);

for (i = 0; i< rowCount1; i++)
    free(mat3[i]);
free(mat3);

free(data);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you post us more details about the errors ?

Comment: here you are : https://scr.hu/ll47Ka

Comment: 1) Please post the errors here, not a link to another site.  2) Pick a language -- it's either C or it's C++.

Comment: LNK2019 - unresolved external symbol _getline referenced in function _main line 1   LNK1120 - 1 unresolved external line 1  . Its just C.

Comment: yea sorry im new to this site i just put the recommended tags

Comment: can someone help defining getline in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Visual C++, there is no such `C` function as `getline`.  The `C` compiler that comes with Visual C++ adheres to the `C89` specification.

Use `fgets` to retrieve the data from the file.

If you really want to use `getline` in your Visual C++ (really C) program, you could try [this code from GNU](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&ved=0ahUKEwjVzqPt8KPNAhWH2T4KHUTBABw4ChAWCD8wBA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.w3.org%2Flibwww%2FLibrary%2Fsrc%2Fvms%2Fgetline.c&usg=AFQjCNF60QKmKLK0_YXeK4V4wm33Z0CIKQ&bvm=bv.124272578,d.cWw&cad=rja) that implements the function.

Comment: should it be like this : }
 char string[100];
 while (fgets(string, 100, macierz1)) {
  printf("%s\n", string);
  }                                            ??

Comment: See my edits.  I linked to the GNU C implementation of `getline`.

Comment: Just a note, the link provided for `getline` is not to anywhere close to the actual implementation of GNU `getline` and as written is limited to reading a max of `255` chars at a time, regardless of whether that is a complete line.

Answer (score -1):

There is a stray '`' in program posted at the end of the line:

```
if (macierz1 == NULL) {``
```

and

```
getline
```

function is not defined.

add needed includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: i didnt pasted the includes they are here

Comment: its good to use getline here or maybe its better to use fgets?

Comment: Use `fgets` since `getline` does not link to your program.

Comment: This should have been a comment and not an answer